# Difference between nuget packages IBMMQDotnetClient and IBMXMSDotnetClient (IBM MQ support for .Net Core)

Tags: .net-core, nuget, ibm-mq

These packages seem to have similar functionality. What's the difference?

Answer (score 6):

**IBMMQDotnetClient** is "IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard" also known as known as Base .NET Classes.

Where as

**IBMXMSDotnetClient**:  called XMS that has the same set of interfaces as the Java™ Message Service (JMS) API.Renders a JMS-like API and Implements JMS 1.1 Specification. Most of the features available in IBMMQDotnetClient are available in XMS as well and on top of these features,there are additional features like "Asynchronous message consumer", Message selectors, Poison message handling etc.

Basically the difference is if you want to use JMS-like API's and looking for features like Asynchronous message consumer or message selectors,then you can use XMS.

Comment: Is IBMMQDotnetClient more like low-level library?

Comment: @PavelBiryukov the are really just two ways to do it.  XMS has the additional features that subbaraoc mentioned.  If you were comparing them to Java, the IBMMQDotnetClient  is like the "IBM MQ classes for Java" where IBMXMSDotnetClient is like "IBM MQ classes for JMS"

Comment: @JoshMc But "on the wire" are the produced messages the same?

Comment: They can be.  XMS like JMS will add  RHF2 header,  but this can be easily turned off on the sending side by setting targetClient.

Comment: It seams I can't add custom MQRFH2 headers with xms, only supported by JMS...

Comment: I don't think that is true, message properties are supported in XMS.

Comment: @JoshMc You're right! 
I was trying to set textMessage.SetStringProperty("MQRFH2.usr.SENDER", "CUSTOM_SENDER");
and it gave and error
But just setting textMessage.SetStringProperty("SENDER", "CUSTOM_SENDER");
sets MQRFH2.usr.SENDER (checked with amqsbcg)