# IBMMQDotnetClient vs IBMXMSDotnetClient

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am working on a project, which needs to connect to IBM MQ using c#, and considering which NuGet package is the best one.

However, there are 2 NuGet packages **IBMMQDotnetClient** and **IBMXMSDotnetClient** and both of them are provided by the official (IBM).

After reading a few references,

[Difference between nuget packages IBMMQDotnetClient and IBMXMSDotnetClient (IBM MQ support for .Net Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301439/difference-between-nuget-packages-ibmmqdotnetclient-and-ibmxmsdotnetclient-ibm)

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/xms-net-%E2%80%93-overview

It looks like that me that there are 2 main differences between these 2 API.

1. **IBMXMSDotnetClient** provides more functionalities
2. **IBMXMSDotnetClient** provides JMS-like API. If someone is using Java before, it is more easier to port the Java code to .Net

Another difference I noticed is that the way they are connecting to the MQ server (QueueManager vs Connection and Session). But it is **not** really a problem, just different styles as far as I can see.

**IBMMQDotnetClient**

```
MQEnvironment.Hostname = hostName;
MQEnvironment.Channel = channel;
// Queue Manager object
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
MQQueue system_default_local_queue = queueManager .AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
```

**IBMXMSDotnetClient**

```
XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory;
IConnectionFactory cf;
IDestination destination;
factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
// Queue Manager just as an simple string property here
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName);
```

If it is the case, I cannot see any reason why I do not choose **IBMXMSDotnetClient**.

But the weird thing is that there are 327K downloads for **IBMMQDotnetClient** while there are only 160k downloads for **IBMXMSDotnetClient**.

Or there are some key advantages of **IBMMQDotnetClient** I missed?

Comment: There will be numerous things that you can do via the MQI that you can't do via JMS - the question is whether you need any of those MQ specific things.

Comment: Hi @MoragHughson Thanks for your reply. Would you mind sharing some of the things which can only be done by IBMMQDotnetClient  but not by IBMXMSDotnetClient?

Comment: How about MQPMO_PASS_ALL_CONTEXT or using an alternate user id? Not 100% certain of exactly which features are not in JMS/XMS but it is those sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks, @MoragHughson for the hint. I will explore further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBMMQDotNet provides MQ native APIs in .NET language while IBMXMSDotNet provides JMS style of APIs in .NET. However there is one major difference between the two APIs: IBMXMSDotNet provides asynchronous message consumer while IBMMQDotNet does not. Asynchronous message consumption is a type of consuming messages where IBMXMSDotNet automatically calls application registered callback method whenever a message arrives in MQ queue. With IBMMQDotNet, you will need to do a synchronous Get call (with or without timeout) to receive messages.

Hope this helps

**Update: 16th May 2022**
One example: In case of MQDotNet, you can change selection criteria to read messages matching another criteria without reopening a queue. For example you can say "select message matching groupId x" first from the queue to read messages matching the given groupId. Then you can say "select message matching groupId y" from the same queue without reopening queue. In case of XMSDotNet, the selection createria is specified while creating the consumer (which internally opens a MQ queue). Consumer must be recreated if you want to change selection criteria to consume messages with another criteria

Comment: These seem to be the key advantages of IBMXMSDotnetClient. OP asked for key advantages of IBMMQDotnetClient.

Comment: @Shashi Thanks for your reply. As mentioned by MoragHughson. This is the key advantage of IBMXMSDotNet. But I want to know if there are any advantages of IBMMQDotNet over IBMXMSDotNet.

Comment: IBMMQDotNet provides a fine grained control on what you want do with MQ, while IBMXMSDotNet abstracts a lot to make application development easier. Providing brief details of your project (if possible) may help.

Comment: @Shashi At this moment, just need to send/receive messages from the IBM MQ server and need to support transaction. Do you mind further elaborate what you mean by "fine grained control"?

Comment: One example: In case of MQDotNet, you can change selection criteria to read messages matching another criteria without reopening a queue. For example you can say "select message matching groupId x" first from the queue to read messages matching the given groupId. Then you can say "select message matching groupId y" from the same queue without reopening queue. In case of XMSDotNet, the selection createria is specified while creating the consumer (which internally opens a MQ queue). Consumer must be recreated if you want to change selection criteria to consume messages with another criteria.

Comment: Thanks, @Shashi. Would you mind changing your comment to answer so that I can accept it as solution?

Comment: @kzfid - Updated answer.